# Initial width on iphone / ipad

Tags: iphone, html, css, ipad, mobile-safari

i'm using this template for wordpress:

http://demos.itsmattadams.com/jetwire/

When I try to load on iphone/ipad, the page don't fit to all wide because only show a portion. I don't want horizontal scroll either.

If I open the theme from a ThemeForest link, works good (maybe for the iframe?):

http://themeforest.net/item/jetwire-powerful-wordpress-blog-theme/full_screen_preview/2919709

I tried to change the main container width to 960px, but don't work.

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

The site should then automatically fit inside the viewport. This line is basically telling the device to take the pixelwidth of the device (`width=device-width`) and match it to your site, by 'zooming in'.
Say your site is 960px wide, and the device is 320px wide; it will then only show the leftmost part (320px wide) of the site, leaving 640px 'flowing over' to the right.
Not specifying a viewport width will force the device to show the full site.

Comment: Works!! I knew this line, but had not seen it in code. THANKS!